# I just deleted my app from firebase console , but it is still working and changing data in the realtime database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, flutter

I just deleted my flutter app from firebase console , but it is still working and changing data in the realtime database.
Can anyone tell me how its still connected with the firebase?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Access to the realtime database is not limited to apps that are registered in the Firebase console. Any code that has the proper configuration for your database, can try to access that database. If you want to be more selective in who can access the database, you will need to do this with Firebase's server-side security rules, typically in combination with Firebase Authentication.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Firebase documentation](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7047853?hl=en), when you delete an app:

> Corresponding API keys or OAuth clients are NOT deleted. You can clean
>   up the API keys or OAuth clients in the [Google APIs console
>   credentials](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials) page. Deleting these resources will break installed
>   applications: your users will no longer be able to authenticate or
>   sign in.